# How to Access the openbravo XML/Rest API's for the individual Client?

Tags: java, json, xml, rest, openbravo

When I'm trying access the rest/xml api it is asking for the username and password, the default username and password is 'Openbravo' and 'openbravo' respectively. But I have a created a client with in the openbravo and organisations related to that client. so, for this also I need to give the default  username and password what what if I want to access the organisation details based on the client because I cannot find the organisation details from the default username and password. Please help me fix it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can provide any client or organization user id with password but make sure that the same user should be set it as default with default role, organization etc in Profile tab ( Used to switch roles / organizations in openbravo )